# UIWebView in iOS Swift project give a white screen and the output "error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted"

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, crosswalk

I have a problem with a very simple iOS Swift project. The intention is for it to load a URL via UIWebView (eventually Crosswalk). My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height));       
        let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.www.google.com/");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView);
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

When it runs (iOS 9.3.4 on an iPod Touch 6th Gen 16b, if that matters), it displays an entirely white screen and sits there. After a short while, the Xcode output window displays:

> error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? Does the code look ok? Perhaps I set things up incorrectly? I've looked around and everyone has a different answer for it, but none of those seem to be the problem for me.

I know very little about iOS and Swift development so I apologize if this is a trivial problem, but I'd appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: You have two **www** in your url: `https://www.www.google.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know you add TransportSecurity to your info.plist or not if not add thus line of code to your project since from ios 9 apple change TransportSecurity then in your code you have 2 'www' in "https://www.www.google.com/" I fixed that and checked, it's work like charm

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>your.URL.come</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Hes using `https` so `NSAppTransportSecurity` isn't necessary.

Comment: i just changed url and your code is all right and worked 'let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.google.com/");'

Comment: I'm very embarrassed to say that the typo was the problem! I was unaware of being able to add properties like those you have listed to info.plist. I'll be looking at Apple's docs to see what fits. Thanks!